# After updating to Angular 1.3 my TypeScript class is undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I use the controller as patter in my view and after upgrading Angular to 1.3 my controller is undefined. I can use a lambda in the Angular registration of my controller and it doesn't crash on undefined, but the binding to my controller doesn't work.

My controller:

```
module MyModule {
"use strict";

    angular.module("app").controller("MyController", ["$location", "$rootScope", MyController]);

    private MyString: string;
    export class MyController {
        constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService,
            $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
            this.MyString = "My String";
        }
    }
}
```

And in my view:

```
<section data-ng-controller="MyModule.MyController as vm">
    ...
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some JavaScript inheritance/prototype magic it seems I have gotten my TypeScript class in a module to play with Angular 1.3.

In essence I create a function that inherits from my TypeScript class, and use that as my Angular controller instead.

I created a function that inherits from my MyController:

```
function myInheritedController(
    $location: ng.ILocationService,
    $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
    // Call the constructor of the Parent class
    MyController.call(this, $location, $rootScope);
}

// This is JavaScript inheritance.
myInheritedController.prototype = Object.create(MyController.prototype);
myInheritedController.prototype.constructor = myInheritedController;
```

I change my view to use the actual string that I register the controller with:

```
<section data-ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    ...
</section>
```

The TypeScript class remains the same and angular registration is changed to use the new function. The complete TypeScript file is:

```
module MyModule {
"use strict";

    angular.module("MyController", ["$location", "$rootScope", myInheritedController]);

    private MyString: string;
    export class MyController {
        constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService,
            $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
            this.MyString = "My String";
        }
    }

    function myInheritedController(
        $location: ng.ILocationService,
        $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
        MyController.call(this, $location, $rootScope);
    }

    myInheritedController.prototype = Object.create(MyController.prototype);
    myInheritedController.prototype.constructor = myInheritedController;
}
```

I'm not a JavaScript expert in any means. It took a fair bit of googling and experimenting to arrive at this solution. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution, or a completely different solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

this is how i make controller's its quite clean

```
module portal {

  var app =angular.module("demoApp",[]);
      app.controller(controllers); //i am just adding the namespace 
} 

module portal.controllers{
 //add any other controllers in this namespace and by magic it will get reigstered 

export class demoController{

 constructor($scope){
//do your suff
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> With some JavaScript inheritance/prototype magic it seems I have gotten my TypeScript class in a module to play with Angular 1.3.

In your answer instead of :

```
function myInheritedController(
    $location: ng.ILocationService,
    $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
    MyController.call(this, $location, $rootScope);
}

myInheritedController.prototype = Object.create(MyController.prototype);
myInheritedController.prototype.constructor = myInheritedController;
```

You can do:

```
class myInheritedController extends MyController{
    constructor(
    $location: ng.ILocationService,
    $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
      super($location, $rootScope);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I had was that my TypeScript class would not work as a controller in AngularJS 1.3. I (pure speculation) believe it might be because TypeScript generates the class as a var to an anonymous function. Further wilder speculation is perhaps it's how anonymous functions prototypes work. Anyhoo the JavaScript inheritance prototype magic allowed me to have a named function to make AngularJS happy, but still put the actual logic in a TypeScript class. To use TypeScript inheritance still produces a var to an anonymous function and it wouldn't help me.